# Como pegar o valor de um Dropdownlist para escolher a action a ser executada

Tags: asp.net-mvc, gridview, view, dropdown

peço a ajuda de vocês no sentido de me auxiliar a montar a seguinte situação:

Tenho uma estrutura em EF database first onde tenho um tipo que o usuário deve selecionar e após selecionar este tipo na dropdownlist o mesmo deve disparar uma ação correspondente. Por exemplo:

Se na Dropdonwlist esta em branco, nada acontece, se o usuário selecionar por exemplo importar arquivo, deve apresentar na view um input file onde irei buscar o arquivo e após clicar em submit irá executar a ação correspondente no controller.

Agora se o usuário selecionar por exemplo exportação, deve apresentar na view uma lista dos arquivos disponíveis para ele baixar, e se o usuário selecionar pergunta por exemplo, deve montar um form para enviar um e-mail.

Hoje scaffold que o VS montou, e já adaptando montei a seguinte estrutura em create:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
  tbCliente usrCliente = _repositorio.ObterCliente(this.User.Identity.Name);
  SelectList(db.tbCliente, "IdCliente", "Nome");
  ViewBag.idTipoServico = new SelectList(db.TipoServicoes, "idTipoServico", "TipoServico1");
  return View();
}
```

---

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "idSolicitacao,idCliente,idTipoServico,idAviso,DataSolicitacao,AvisoEncaminhado,AvisoLido")] Solicitacao solicitacao)
{
  tbCliente usrCliente = _repositorio.ObterCliente(this.User.Identity.Name);
  if (ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    solicitacao.idCliente = usrCliente.IdCliente;
    solicitacao.idAviso = 2;
    solicitacao.AvisoEncaminhado = 1;
    solicitacao.AvisoLido = 0;
    solicitacao.DataSolicitacao = DateTime.Now;
    solicitacao.idStatus = 1;
    db.Solicitacaos.Add(solicitacao);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index");
  }
  SelectList(db.tbCliente, "IdCliente", "Nome", solicitacao.idCliente);
        ViewBag.idTipoServico = new SelectList(db.TipoServicoes, "idTipoServico", "TipoServico1", solicitacao.idTipoServico);
  return View(solicitacao);
}
```

---

Na minha view está assim, mas teria que fazer ela funcionar da forma que mencionei acima.

```
@model FlowTec.Models.Solicitacao
@{
   ViewBag.Title = "Create";
   Layout = "~/Areas/Clientes/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
 }
 <h2>Create</h2>
 @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
 {
 @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Solicitacao</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.idTipoServico, "idTipoServico", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.DropDownList("idTipoServico", String.Empty)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.idTipoServico)
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}
<div>
   @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

---

Mapeamento da tabela de solicitao feita pelo EF.

```
namespace Empresa.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Solicitacao
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Solicitacao()
    {
        this.tbArquivoes = new HashSet<tbArquivo>();
    }

    public int idSolicitacao { get; set; }
    public int idCliente { get; set; }
    public int idTipoServico { get; set; }
    public int idAviso { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime DataSolicitacao { get; set; }
    public byte AvisoEncaminhado { get; set; }
    public byte AvisoLido { get; set; }
    public int idStatus { get; set; }

    public virtual Aviso Aviso { get; set; }
    public virtual tbCliente tbCliente { get; set; }
    public virtual TipoServico TipoServico { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<tbArquivo> tbArquivoes { get; set; }
    public virtual StatusSolicitacao StatusSolicitacao { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Alguém tem alguma ideia de como posso montar isso de forma mais dinâmica possível. O que preciso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Em resumo, jQuery, Ajax e *Partials*.

Explicando mais, `idTipoServico` deve ser monitorada pelo jQuery. Algo assim:

```
$(document).on("change", "#idTipoServico", function() {
    switch ($(this).val()) {
        case 1:
            // Executa alguma coisa
            break;
        case 2:
            // Executa outra coisa
            break;           
        default:
            // Ação default
            break; 
    }
});
```

Cada ação vai popular sua tela de um jeito diferente. Para cada uma, é boa prática implementar uma *Action* em *Controller* para devolver a *Partial* correspondente ao tipo de serviço:

```
    public ActionResult BlocoImportarArquivo()
    {
        return PartialView("_ImportarArquivo", new ViewModelDaImportacaoDeArquivo { Id = Guid.NewGuid() });
    }
```

Na *Partial* você coloca todo e qualquer HTML que precisar. Evite colocar JS pra não virar bagunça.

Voltando ao código do `switch`, o bloco a seguir insere o HTML de uma *Partial* gerada em *Controller* dentro de uma `<div>` na *View* (isto pode ser colocado em *Partial*, se quiser):

```
$.get('/MeuController/BlocoImportarArquivo', function (template) {
    $("#div-do-bloco").append(template);
});
```

Comment: Mendez, vou tentar logo mais e ai posto a resposta. Mas de ante mão quero agradecer pela força. Obrigado